# Java how to create and ordered tree structure using recursion and Nodes?

Tags: java, recursion, tree, nodes

I'm trying to build a code that an ArrayList of Nodes to create a tree structure for parsing and printing phylogenetic trees. When parsing using this recursive function a few of the elements seem to be getting left out, and not being inserted where they should be.

```
{
public void buildTree(ArrayList<Node> T) {

        for(int i = 0; i < T.size()-1; i++) {
            for( int j = i+1; j < T.size()-1; j++) {
                while(j < T.size() && T.get(j).name.startsWith(T.get(i).name)) {
                    T.get(i).children.add(T.get(j));
                    T.remove(j);
                    Collections.sort(T.get(i).children, NAME);
                    buildTree(T.get(i).children);

                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

This code takes a list of nodes, compares every node to each other node and adds it to its branch if its a descendant ( String.startsWith() comparison ). I was supposed to see this result:

```
{
*
|-AAAAGAC
| |-AAAAGACTGG
|-AAAATC
|-AAATA
|-AAATCGA
|-AAATT
| |-AAATTAAG
| |-AAATTC
| | |-AAATTCAAC
| | | |-AAATTCAACA
| | | |-AAATTCAACG
| | | |-AAATTCAACT
| | | | |-AAATTCAACTA
| | | | |-AAATTCAACTT
| | |-AAATTCCGA
}
```

But instead I keep getting this:

```
{
*
|-AAAAGAC
| |-AAAAGACTGG
|-AAAATC
|-AAATA
|-AAATCGA
|-AAATT
| |-AAATTAAG
| |-AAATTC
| | |-AAATTCAAC
| | | |-AAATTCAACA
| | | |-AAATTCAACG
| | | |-AAATTCAACT
| | | |-AAATTCAACTA <<<<<<<<< Needs one more indent.
| | | | |-AAATTCAACTT
| |-AAATTCCGA <<<<<<<<< Needs one more indent.
}
```

Why is the code giving too few indents?

Comment: Please copy the link of where you got it, or copy and paste it here.

Comment: Please see: [How to debug small programs (external link)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: can you check the first sentence? (you mean "..code that uses,,"?)

Comment: If you want to iterate over an entire list use `i < T.size()`  instead of `i < T.size()-1` . For more help please post [mcve]